# Self-study Graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, book-recommendation

I decided to self-study graph theory. I am not newbie in it as I have experience from programming, like I know graph algorithms and how  they work, have some experience with discrete mathematics(well, that includes matching problems, coloring). However, I would like to take a book with nice theorems and proofs that will be interesting for someone like me with previous little experience with graphs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this [book](https://cs.bme.hu/fcs/graphtheory.pdf) by Tero Harju. It's a nice read. In case you want a classic book you can also use the famous book by [Prof. Douglas West](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/igt/).

Comment: @VineetKumar What's the advantage of Harju's book? Just looking over the first chapter, it seems to use awkward nonstandard notation $\nu_G, \epsilon_G$ for the number of vertices and edges in $G$, and got the definition of a walk wrong: a sequence $e_1e_2\dots e_k$ where $e_i$ is adjacent to $e_{i+1}$ allows us to take a sequence of $k$ edges all incident to the same vertex. I would stick with the classics.

Comment: Since OP is aware of the basics of the graph. I think this Harju's book will help him choose what to study. Sorry.. Didn't noticed that Walk defn is wrong. [This](https://book.huihoo.com/pdf/graph-theory-With-applications/) classic by Boondy and Murty is also very nice for more details.